# read datatable again after clicking the submit Button

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I want my dataTable to be read again or reload the data from db after clicking update/submit button.

i tried this

```
$('#ManageForms').dataTable().dataSource.read();
```

it seemed to work with kendoUI but i guess datatables must have different procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reload the entire table then [fnReloadAjax()](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax) is the way to go. It will go to the server, and just grab everything again.

**Example:**

```
    var table = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Example call to load a new file
  table.fnReloadAjax( 'media/examples_support/json_source2.txt' );

  // Example call to reload from original file
  table.fnReloadAjax();
```

If you want to load only the data that should be displayed, then you need to use the [bServerSide](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) parameter, and have the server reply to your request, taking into account, filtering etc.

Comment: Please explain how to use those functions as link-only answers are discouraged. Too often, links will die, and we want to preserve answers here. You just need to provide a basic gist of how to use it, you don't have to provide every minute detail that the link provides.

Comment: `TypeError: oTable.fnReloadAjax is not a function`
i tried `table.fnReloadAjax();` where i changed the table to the variable i have assigned `oTable`. `var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();`

Comment: i guess i have to add js file for this API fnReloadAjax, as you provived the link, its an API.

Cant the grid be reloaded without adding the whole API.

Comment: you win. i couldnt find anyother way to refresh grid without API.
Finally Added the API for fnReloadAjax.